# Is there any way to sort on a nested value in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any way to sort on a nested value in Azure Cognitive Search?

My use case is that I have a database of songs that are associated with dances that one can dance to that song.  Users can vote on the danceability of a dance to a song, so there is a is a numeric vote tally for each song/dance combination.  A core part of the functionality for the search is to be able to do an arbitrary search and sort the results by the popularity of a particular dance.

I am currently modeling this by creating a new top level field with a decorated name (e.g. DNC_Salsa or DNC_Waltz) for each dance.  This works.  But aside from being clumsy, I can't associate other information with a dance.  In addition, I have to dynamically add the dance fields, so I have to use the generic SearchDocument type in the C# library rather than using a POCO type.

I'd much prefer to model this with the dance fields as an array of subdocuments where the subdocuments contain a dance name, a vote count and the other information I'd like to associate with a dance.

A simplified example record would look something like this:

```
{
    "title": "Baby, It's Cold Outside",
    "artist": "Seth MacFarlane",
    "tempo": 119.1,
    "dances": [
        { "name", "cha cah", "votes", 1 },
        { "name", "foxtrot", "votes", 4 }
    ]   
}
```

I gave this a try and received:

```
{"error":{"code":"OperationNotAllowed","message":"The request is invalid.","details":[{"code":"CannotEnableFieldForSorting","message":"The field 'Votes' cannot be enabled for sorting because it is directly or indirectly contained in a collection, which makes it a multi-valued field. Sorting is not allowed on multi-valued fields. Parameters: definition"}]}}
```

It looks like elastic search will do what I want:
[Sort search results | Elasticsearch Guide [7.17] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sort-search-results.html#_nested_sorting_examples)

If I'm reading the Elasticsearch documetion correctly, you can basically say I'd like to sort on the dances subdocument by first filtering for name == "cha cha" and then sorting on the vote field.

Is there anything like this in Azure Cognitive Search?  Or even something more restrictive?  I don't need to do arbitrary sorting on anything in the subdocument.  I would be happy to only ever sort on the vote count (although I'd have to be able to do that for any dance name).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your records or data model looks like. However, from the error message you provided, it's clear that you try to sort on a multivalue property. That is logically impossible.

Imagine a property Color that can contain colors like 'Red' or 'Blue'. If you sort by Color, you would get your red values before the blues. If you instead had 'Colors' that can contain multiple values like both 'Red' and 'Blue', how would you sort it? You can't.

So, if you actually want to *sort* by a property, that property has to contain a single value.

When that's said, I have a feeling you are really asking about ranking/boosting. Not sorting. Have a look at the examples with boosting and scoring profiles for different genres of music. I believe the use case in these examples could help you solve your use case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles#extended-example

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I was hoping that there might be something like scoring profiles that I could hack, but I don't think that will work for me even if I created a different scoring profile for each dance it doesn't look like I can do anything with numeric sorting scoring profiles.

Comment: Also - I have to respectfully disagree with this being "logically impossible" - I expanded my example a bit and put a note in on how I believe elasticsearch handles this case.  And in any case, I could certainly write this algorithm in C# - it would just prohibitively costly for me to load the results of the search to sort it myself...